# in ways that the mind is not

Tags: meaning

What would you paraphrase the following sentence?

> The body is limited in ways that the mind is not.

I think this sentence means, "The body is limited, but the mind is not."

Am I right?

Comment: Kind of. The body is limited (let's say that your body can't travel from New York to Tokyo in a few seconds) in ways (such as that) that your mind is not (while in New York, you can imagine that you are in Tokyo; thus your mind can travel there in a few seconds while your body can't).

Comment: I wouldn't paraphrase it at all, since it's an elegant and precise yet succinct statement of a fairly complex concept.

Comment: As@Hot Licks remarks, the original poster scores over other forms of this statement just as mind scores over body

Answer (score 2):

The *ways* here are "manners in which something takes place".

The body is limited in certain manners, in certain ways.

Of those, some do not apply to the mind.

It doesn't say that the mind is not **also** limited in ways that don't limit the body.

It doesn't say that there are not ways in which **both** mind and body are limited.

It doesn't say that the mind is limited either.

It doesn't speak of those at all, it does says that there are some ways in which the body is limited, that do not limit the mind.

> What would you paraphrase the following sentence?

Perhaps as:

> There are ways in which the body is limited that do not affect the mind.

Though really, I wouldn't at all, the original is better—succinct, clear to a native speaker, and idiomatic—and I can't think of anything that would improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong. The sentence does not suggest that the mind is not limited.

The sentence sugggests that there are certain limitations that apply to the body and not to the mind.